# How do I delete all files with a given name in all subdirectories?

Tags: shell, directory, rm

I want to delete all files with a given name in all the subdirectories of my home directory.

I tried:

```
rm -r file
```

in my home directory, but it didn't work because that file doesn't exist in that directory.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`find . -name "filename" -delete`

Answer (score 21):

as an elaboration on @tante's answer, you may wish to ensure the file list used is correct before deleting those files:

```
find <source_dir> -name <filename> -print
```

if inspection shows valid list then

```
find <source_dir> -name <filename> -delete
```

another option if wanting this over many directories using a temporary holding directory:

```
mkdir <dest_dir>
for i in <list_of_directories>
do
  find "$i" -name <filename> -exec /bin/mv {} <dest_dir>
done

# check dest_dir
ls dest_dir
rm -rf <dest_dir>
```

As always, please ensure the accuracy of any scripts before execution and always have a backup ready in-case something goes wrong.

Comment: always put double quotes around variable substitutions, or your command won't work with file names containing certain special characters (whitespace, wildcards and backslashes).

Comment: @Gilles - Yes, thanks for updating and ensuring this answer was correct.